# RDLC - Sorting items based on row value

Tags: rdlc, dynamic-rdlc-generation

It's hard to explain, but basically, I want this:

Description Category Color 
    apple         Fruit      Red   
    mango       Fruit    Yellow  
    cabbage Vegetable Green 
    carrot      Vegetable Orange 
    brocolli   Vegetable Green

to turn into this:

Description  Color 
**Fruit** 
apple            Red 
mango        Yellow 
**Vegetable** 
cabbage     Green 
carrot         Orange 
brocolli        Green

How would I do this in rdlc?

Comment: You are asking too broad a question.  You are asking “How do I use the SSRS Report Tool.”  Here is a Hint: Get your first query working in SQL. Access, Oracle first. Then Fire Up the Report builder to get the result you want.  Your starting query will be like this:  SELECT Category, Description, Color FROM MyFruitTable   This overly simplisic query is all you need. Then you start working in Report Builder.

Comment: Getting the data isn't the problem, it's about how to organize them in the report builder tool. I need to organize them in a certain manner which I posted in my question.

Answer (score 0):

Add Row Group based on Category followed by Description and Color as columns and you can sort in group properties.